# How to insert text label on faceted time series data using the forecast package in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, forecast

I am doing time series analysis in R using the forecast package. The forecast::autoplot() creates a ggplot object.

I have two questions about plotting decomposed series:

1. How do I place text in the trend panel (next to the vertical red line). Using ggplot or other packages?
2. How can I rename the "data" panel to be capitalized as "Data"?

Here is my code:

```
library(forecast)    

# Load in AirPassengers time series
data("AirPassengers")

# Decomopose time series
decomposed_ts <- decompose(AirPassengers)

# Plot decomposed time series
forecast::autoplot(decomposed_ts) + geom_vline(xintercept = 1954, colour = "red")
```

[image: Screenshot of two questions]

For Q1, I tried to use annotate() but it places the same text labels on each facet, whereas I only want one label on only the trend panel (see screenshot). I also tried to use the ggtext package, but could not get it to work. I couldn't figure out what the faceted variable is because forecast::autoplot() automatically created the faceting.

For Q2. I saved the plot as a variable i.e. myPlot <- forecast::autoplot(decomposed_ts) + geom_vline(xintercept = 1954, colour = "red"). I then tried myPlot$ looking for where the "data" facet is named.

Comment: [See if this helps](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:mobQGwOtvp8J:https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-change-ggplot-facet-labels/&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

Comment: You can see the code used for this plot by typing `forecast:::autoplot.decomposed.ts` in the console. Edit it as required.

Comment: On question 2 
See `str(p[["data"]][["parts"]])` or
`levels(p[["data"]][["parts"]])`
In this case "data", "trend", "seasonal", "remainder"
That is,  a factor named parts with four levels.

Comment: Hi Rob thanks for your work on the forecast package, and also for putting your textbooks online at https://otexts.com/fpp2/ and https://otexts.com/fpp3/ they have been very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add geom_text to the original auto_plot:

```
annotation <- data.frame(
  x = c(1950),
  y = c(250),
  parts = c("trend"),
  label = c("label 1")
)

forecast::autoplot(decomposed_ts) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1954, colour = "red") +
  geom_text(data = annotation, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label))
```

[image: Adding a layer to autoplot]

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure someone smarter than me could dig into the architecture of a ggplot2 plot, but you could make your own autoplot function to keep it a little simpler(ish). Here I added a facet label argument to solve your problem:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)    


my_new_autoplot <- function(decomp, 
                            facet_labels = c("data", "trend", "seasonal", "remainder")){
  list(
tibble(Time = time(decomp$x),
       val = decomp$x,
       type = facet_labels[1]),

tibble(Time = time(decomp$trend),
       val = decomp$trend,
       type = facet_labels[2]),

tibble(Time = time(decomp$seasonal),
       val = decomp$seasonal,
       type = facet_labels[3]),

tibble(Time = time(decomp$random),
       val = decomp$random,
       type = facet_labels[4]) |>
  mutate(t1 = pmax(0, val),
         t2 = pmin(val, 0),
         val = 0)
) |>
  bind_rows() |>
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = facet_labels)) |>
  ggplot(aes(Time, val))+
  geom_path()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = t2, ymax = t1))+
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y", strip.position = "left")+
  labs(y = "")
}

my_new_autoplot(decomposed_ts) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1954, colour = "red")
```

[image]

```r
my_new_autoplot(decomposed_ts, 
                facet_labels = c("my_data!", "trend..", "~seasonal~", "rEmainDeR")) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1954, colour = "red")
```

[image]

And if we wanted to add text, we can do that too:

```r
my_plot <- my_new_autoplot(decomposed_ts, 
                facet_labels = c("my_data!", "trend..", "~seasonal~", "rEmainDeR")) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1954, colour = "red")


add_text <- function(plot, facet, text, x, y, ...){
  text_data <- tibble(Time = x, val = y, type = facet, label = text) |>
    mutate(type = factor(type, levels = levels(plot$data$type)))
  
  plot+
    geom_text(data = text_data, aes(label = label), ...)
}

add_text(plot = my_plot, 
         facet = "rEmainDeR", 
         text = "This is red", 
         x = 1955, 
         y = 40,
         color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. You are smarter than you give yourself credit for :).